# How to quit webdriver, while browser already closed by application

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm testing web application with `Selenium Webdriver (IE)`. After signing off, application closes the browser, but quiting the webdriver cause crash popup for `IEDriverServer.exe` which hangs the flow.

Is there's a way to unload the `IEDriverServer.exe` after browser was closed?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this in various ways. One logic i can think of is to do getWindowHandles() and call driver.quit() based on the window count. In your case after logoff it will be null.

Comment: When I call driver.quit, the list of handles is already empty (size=0), and any driver method (other than quit) causes the "Unable to get browser" exception.

Comment: Get handles and then call driver.quit

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exact solution but, for Workaround, you can try this out :

1. use `driver.close()`
2. If first option doesn't work then open the browser once again and use `driver.quit()` or `driver.close()`.

Comment: driver.close() will not shut down the IEDriverServer.exe, you need to perform a driver.quit() instead.  Secondly driver.close() will error if the object has already been destroyed, whereas driver.quit() will not.  Basically always use driver.quit(), it's safer and more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with an earlier version, which version are you using? There may be a newer version of IEServerDriver than what you have.  I placed mine in a directory that I then added to system PATH and have no troubles with Chromedriver or IEServerDriver.